# Race condition in spring Controller

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I have a code snippet as below, which will make sure that some user action is allowed only limited number of times.

```
1. @Value("${x.y.z.maxRetriesAllowed}")
2.  int maxAllowedRetries; 
3.  int retryLimit = --maxAllowedRetries;
```

And when this goes to static code analysis (fortify), the tool reporting that there is a possible race condition at line 3.

Someone please suggest how can we avoid that without help of session object.

Answer (score 0):

What about this?

```
int retryLimit = this.getRetries();

private synchronized int getRetries()
{
    return --this.maxAllowedRetires;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are relying on maxAllowedRetries to be initialized by Spring before retryLimit, which of course is not likely. Basically, it probably comes out as 0 now. Because the field initializes before Spring populates the value and retryLimit gets initialized when the object is created.

Comment: I think once the request comes in, then only the code in controller method will start executing. So by that time spring makes the maxAllowedRetries to be available for further use.

Comment: these are instance variables, right? So they would both get initialized to zero when the object gets created and then sometime later spring sets maxAllowedRetries. Anyway, write a test for this and you'll see what's happening.